# How to improve the performance of this MongoDB / Mongoose query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have a GET all products endpoint which is taking an extremely long time to return responses:

```
Product.find(find, function(err, _products) {
  if (err) {
    res.status(400).json({ error: err })
    return
  }

  res.json({ data: _products })

}).sort( [['_id', -1]] ).populate([
  { path: 'colors', model: 'Color' },
  { path: 'size', model: 'Size' },
  { path: 'price', model: 'Price' }
]).lean()
```

This query is taking up to *4 seconds*, despite there only being 60 documents in the products collection.

This query came from a previous developer, and I'm not so familiar with Mongoose.

What are the performance consequences of `sort` and `populate`? I assume `populate` is to blame here? I am not really sure what `populate` is doing, so I'm unclear how to either avoid it or index at a DB level to improve performance.

Comment: You could create an index by doing `db.products.createIndex({'_id': '-1''});` but I doubt thats the problem, its most likely the "joins" done by `populate` which is sapping the energy.   Using `explain()` at the end of the chain might shed some light as well.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on `explain()`

Answer (score 6):

From the `Mongoose` docs, *"Population is the process of automatically replacing the specified paths in the document with document(s) from other collection(s)"*

So your `ObjectId` reference on your `model` gets replaced by an entire `Mongoose` `document`. Doing so on multiple paths in one `query` will therefore slow down your app. If you want to keep the same code structure, you can use `select` to specify what fields of the `document` that should be populated, i.e. `{ path: 'colors', model: 'Color', select: 'name' }`. So instead of returning all the data of the `Color` `document` here, you just get the name.

You can also call `cursor()` to stream `query` results from `MongoDB`:

```
var cursor = Person.find().cursor();
cursor.on('data', function(doc) {
  // Called once for every document
});
cursor.on('close', function() {
  // Called when done
});
```

You can read more about the `cursor` `function` in the `Mongoose` documentation [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-cursor).

In general, try to only use `populate` for specific tasks like getting the name of a color for only one product.

`sort` will not cause any major performance issues until you reach much larger databases.

Hope it helps!